# Conditional probability of dependent random variables

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $ X \sim f_X(x), Y \sim f_Y(y) $ are two dependent random variables and their corresponding PDFs. I want to find a probability $$ P(Y\ge 0 | X+Y\ge 0) .$$ If these variables were independent I'd do the following:
$$ P(Y\ge 0 | X+Y\ge 0)= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_X(x) (1-F_Y(-x))dx $$, where $F_Y(y)$ is a CDF for Y. Is this formula still correct for dependent $X$ and $Y$? If not, how can I compute it then?

Comment: you'll have to know how X and Y are correlated, without that information (which is not f_X or f_Y) there is no way to answer your question.

Comment: You need to use the joint distribution (or density) of X and Y, or equivalently, the distribution (density) for one times the conditional distribution (density) for the other, then integrate (Lebesgue-Stieltjes). Your integral is only valid if X and UY are independent. So you can integrate the conditional density of one against the density of the other, with suitable arguments, which is left as an exercise for you.